# Writing overloaded web service methods

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

I have a web service method with the following signature.

```
[WebMethod]
public void Start(string application, string version){}
```

Due to additional requirements, the method has to receive additional parameters but at the same time support other clients who do not have the latest version yet. So I ended up writing two overloaded methods

```
[WebMethod(MessageName="Start", Description="Start", EnableSession=true)]
public void Start(string application, string version){}

[WebMethod(MessageName="Startv2", Description="Startv2", EnableSession=true)]
public void Start(string application, string version, string exception){}
```

With this scenario, I just ended up writing duplicate code. The code in the  `Startv2` method is the same with `Start` with just additional code for processing the additional parameters.

In the near future, I believe additional parameters will be added again and I would need to write another overload for the method again.

Is there any way to write this without duplicating the codes?

Comment: Can you not call your methods in Cascade (for instance the first one could call the second with exception=null)?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a single method with optional parameters, which your WebMethods can call like so:

```
[WebMethod(MessageName="Start", Description="Start", EnableSession=true)]
public void Start(string application, string version){
    StartHandler(application, version);
}

[WebMethod(MessageName="Startv2", Description="Startv2", EnableSession=true)]
public void Start(string application, string version, string exception){
    StartHandler(application, version, exception);
}

    private void StartHandler(string application, string version, string exception = null) {}
```